# What are some general principles about working in a politically toxic workplace?

Tags: politics

You are a mid-level employee in an organization where the office politics is very toxic all around. How do you survive working in a such environment?

I guess the answer also depends whether you have chosen: 
(1) to involve yourself actively in the political warfare or 
(2) to refrain, keep quiet and avoid confrontation.

In either case, I am interested in learning about some general principles or some good online or printed resources about this issue.

Comment: The book *Office Politics: How to Thrive in a World of Lying, Backstabbing and Dirty Tricks* by Oliver James and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace_politics) look like good places to start. There is also a short and helpful [article](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/work/7-habits-to-win-in-office-politics.html) at lifehack.org.

Comment: I have perhaps a dumb question.  If the environment is this bad and stressful, why don't you leave?

Comment: This question is not a reference to my current situation as I am self-employed. But people might not leave a politically toxic environment for various reasons. Some types of workplace thrive on the politics and there are some industries where an active workplace politics is the norm -- in higher education, for example, or in a political party.

Comment: Hey Peter, as it stands, this question would lead to a lot of short answers based on unsubstantiated claims or "for further reading" and may not even apply to your situation. To get this off hold, consider using real examples in your question. Talk about a real, actual problem you're facing and this will lead to answers that better solve that problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not have a specific actual problem in mind but am only just interested in very general principles regarding toxic workplace politics from a strategic management point of view. I am not in a situation where workplace politics is an issue in my working life. Useful literature giving lists of general strategic principles do exist, like for example the work of Robert Greene or some recent publications distilling the political ideas of Cicero. But I accept that this question might be seen as too broad so I will not pursue it further.